# How to clear all the controls at one time in WPF from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Plz guide me if there is any way that could clear all the controls at once in WPF.

*Problem*: i have a window that has **textboxes**, **Datagrids** etc. So after my job is done i need to clear all the controls. Just imagine a registration form after one is done i need a fresh copy for next registration.
So how to do it from the ViewModel..?

Right now i am clearing one by one control inside a method.
But i want to know if there are any efficient way to do it.

Comment: Bind all them to one viewmodel's properties. New up another instance and set datacontext to that.

Comment: Ok but what about destroying old instance. Let the garbage collector handle or what

Comment: Nuke it from space. It's the only way to be sure. Or.You could just rely on gc if you have no hard references to keep it hanging around.

Comment: Ok let me try ..Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you using `ICommand` with `Binding` you can set all properties to default value:

`ViewModel`:

```
public string Text { get => _text; set => SetProperty(_ref _text, value); } //binding to control in UI

public int SmthIntProperty { get => _smthInt; set => SetProperty(_ref _smthInt, value); } //binding to control in UI

public Command ExampleCommand
{
   get => new Command((_) => 
   {
      //smth code

      Text = string.Empty;
      SmthIntProperty = 0;
   })
}
```